# Could not download maven-fail-safe-plugin. Giving me an error message

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

I have created a new maven project with serenity framework. I am getting this error in my new maven project

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:jar:2.22.1: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:pom:2.22.1 from/to
>   central (http://jcenter.bintray.com): Authorization failed for
>   http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/2.22.1/maven-failsafe-plugin-2.22.1.pom
>   403 Forbidden

Comment: You have to use https instead of http apart from the question why you use jcenter instead of Maven Central ?

Comment: When i enter mvn archetype: generate -Dfilter=serenity

Its directly searching for maven-fail safe plugin on jcenter side and not in maven central

Comment: If so you have configured it as it. I suppose you have configured something in your `settings.xml` file cause the default of Maven is to use Maven Central..and not JCenter...

Comment: Can u help me how can i make changes into settings.xml so it download from Maven central only

Comment: Please check if you have a settings.xml file located in your home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` ? Or if you have changed the `settings.xml` which is located in the installation directory of your Maven installation....

Answer (score 2):

You need change http to https
http://jcenter.bintray.com to https://jcenter.bintray.com

Answer (score 1):

I found this way, just delete these line below in `pom.xml` and it's worked:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had mistakenly removed jcenter configurations from the `~/.m2/settings.xml` while my organization specific repositores. After adding it started working.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'
          xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>

    <servers>
         ...
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>bintray</name>
                    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
                    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <id>bintray</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```